# Question on usage of "clientele"

Tags: collective-nouns

Between these two sentences, which (if either) is correct in American English:

> Our clientele range from a small non-profit to a billion dollar corporation...

or

> Our clientele ranges from a small non-profit to a billion dollar corporation...

A collective noun is usually treated as singular.  If that holds true here, then "ranges" would be correct.  But that just feels wrong.  For some reason I can't quite articulate, "range" feels right.

Thoughts?  Which is correct and why?

Comment: The difference between U.S. English and British English here isn't as big as everybody thinks it is. The collective nouns which are always treated as singular in U.S. English are things like *government*, *Congress*, *Parliament*, *Microsoft*. Words like *clientele* and *family* can be treated as either, depending on whether you're considering them as a collective or as individuals. So: *"our clientele is a very select group"*, but *"our clientele range from …"*.

Comment: Good response.  Wish it had turned into a full-blown answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching verbs to collective nouns

Collective nouns are nouns which stand for a group or collection of people or things. They include words such as audience, committee, police, crew, family, government, group, and team.

In American English, most collective nouns are treated as singular, with a singular verb:

√ The whole family was at the table.
√ The government is doing a good job.
√ He prefers an audience that arrives without expectations.

In British English, most collective nouns can be treated as singular or plural:

The whole family was at the table. [singular collective noun; singular verb]
The whole family were at the table. [plural collective noun; plural verb]

The government is doing a good job. [singular collective noun; singular verb]
The government are doing a good job. [plural collective noun; plural verb]

There are a few collective nouns (in both British and American English) that are always used with a plural verb, the most common of which are police and people:

√ She’s happy with the way the police have handled the case.
X She’s happy with the way the police has handled the case.

√ It's been my experience that people are generally forgiving.
X It's been my experience that people is generally forgiving.

Source : Oxford Dictionary

I have always seen  *clientele* followed by plural verb: *Our clientele range from..*

But, *we need to attract a clientele over 30 of age*

Comment: Thanks; that's about the same conclusion to which I came:  singular should be correct, but inexplcably isn't.